# Spring-Data-Mongo 1.7: org.springframework.data.mongodb.LazyLoadingException Unable to lazily resolve DBRef

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, exception, spring-data-mongodb

I am using `Spring-Data-Mongo 1.7` from last 6 months in our project with `@DBRef` lazy loading technique. My Mongo version is `2.6`. Every thing works fine, but today i got `org.springframework.data.mongodb.LazyLoadingException: Unable to lazily resolve DBRef!` exception, when fetch the data using lazy loading. I am not able to figure out what actual problem is, because there are no changes in our code.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem today. Fortunately upgrading Spring Data Mongo and Mongo driver to the newest version fixed my problem.